# run same SSIS package on two separate schedules with different params

Tags: deployment, ssis, scheduling, ssis-2012

I have a (relatively simple) package that has to run on two identical databases. (A+B)

But for database A it has to run every day until the 3th of october  and for database B it has to run every second day until the first of june.

Now my idea is to create one package that has a param and runs on two schedules. In one schedule the param will cause the package to read from database A, in the other schedule it will cause the package to read from database B.

That sounds very logical and not even overly complicated. But I am not sure as how to implement this practically.

Deploy the package twice? Each deploy with it's own schedule and param setting? Or is it possible to change the parameter per schedule?

What would you do?

Thanx for thinking with me, Henro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would deploy one package.  I would define two jobs in the SQL Server Agent, each with it's own schedule, each passing the appropriate parameter.

You cannot set the parameter per schedule in a single job.